# How to stop auto load on cordova meteor?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I am creating ios app using meteor and i have all the assets in the public folder, but still my app downloads assets from the server when it loads for the first time.

I am trying to stop auto reload or auto update on cordova.

I have tried this but didnt work.

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  Reload._onMigrate(function (retry) {
    return [false];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>[Have you looked at the reload on resume package?](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:reload-on-resume/README.md)</del>  [Not on IOS at this time, sorry!](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/issues/72)

> Add it to your Meteor app with meteor add mdg:reload-on-resume. This
>   package changes the behavior of Meteor's hot code push feature on
>   mobile devices only.
>
> Normally, your app will update on the user's device as soon as you
>   push a new version. This process is always smooth in a desktop web
>   browser, but might momentarily interrupt the user's experience if they
>   are on a mobile device.
>
> With this package, the app will only update itself to the newest
>   version if the user closes and re-opens the app (hence, it "reloads on
>   resume").

[The Appcache package will stop your app downloading when it first loads](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/appcache)

> Once a user has visited a Meteor application for the first time and
>   the application has been cached, on subsequent visits the web page
>   loads faster because the browser can load the application out of the
>   cache without contacting the server first.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities :

### onMigrate

Use this on client side (/client folder)

```
Meteor._reload.onMigrate(function() {
  return [false];
});
```

### AUTOUPDATE_VERSION

```
$ AUTOUPDATE_VERSION=abc meteor
```

You can set the AUTOUPDATE_VERSION environment variable to something static, it will prevent autoupdate.

[See Meteor Doc.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/bc6bfceacf767ae878a20cf164f26b9cbf96493d/packages/autoupdate/QA.md#autoupdate_version)

---

Edit note : mdg:reload-on-resume doesn't work on iOS. [Issue #72.](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/issues/72)

Comment: Time for me to test with IOS!  Thanks @Nicolas